# How to make my columns stack on top of each other using media quires

Tags: html, css, media-queries, block

I'm struggling to figure this one out. Any help or advice will be greatly appreciated.  My aim is when the screens less then 700px the content will go change to a block display from the current side by side columns. But currently my columns just stay side by side. I managed to get it to work in jsfiddle but cant get it to do anything other then narrow together in sublime text.

```css
footer {
  background-color: #333538;
  /* padding: 24px 0; */
  margin-top: 12px;
}
footer p {
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 12px !important;
}
.social {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.social li {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.copyright {
  /* padding: 12px 0; */
  text-align: center;
}
.column-half {
  margin: 0 12px 24px 12px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: blue;
  /*float: left;*/
}
.row-foot {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: 72px;

}
.container {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .row-foot {
    display: block;
  }
  .container {
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row-foot">
      <div class="column-half">
        <h4>BOOK AN APPOINTMENT</h4>
        <p>The Paw Pad is a professioanl dog grooming service based in lytham</p>
        <p>Strit practice to a high hygeine standard ensuring your dog leaves in good health as well as a great coat</p>
        <p>All request are welcome and I'll be happy to help in any way I can</p>
        <p><b>Opening Hours</b></p>
        <p><i>Monday to Friday 10am-5pm</i></p>
      </div> <!-- end column half -->
      <div class="column-half">
        <h4>Get in touch</h4>
        <p>46 aaaaa ddddt</p>
        <p>fy8 gr6</p>
        <p>000000000</p>
        <p><a href="mailto:fdjhgfdhgf@gmail.com">thgfhgfhgs@gmail.com</a></p>
        <li class="social"><a href="#"><img src="C:\Users\Sue\Desktop\sublime-
          text\images/facebook-logo2.png" alt="Facebook"></a></li>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
```

Comment: I would use Flexbox with different `flex-direction` (row/column) : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Please set it as code snippet

Comment: thanks, i'll have a look into that.

Comment: its worked! i used a flex-wrap. Should be useful for the future. thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, there are problems in your CSS and also in your HTML syntax.

For the HTML:

The `li` element inside the second "column half" `div` ought to be inside an `ul` or `ol` element.

do something like

```
<ul class="social"><li>............type the rest here</li></ul>
```

For the CSS:

add screen or all to your media query declaration as follows

```
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {}
```

Comment: thanks pawel for that edit. it looks nicer now. just observed it. forgive me, i am new here.

Comment: you are welcome peakinho. let me know if it solved it